# iAd external window popup

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, external, iad

Can someone tell me what I need to type into my ViewController so that when a user might actually end up clicking an iAd banner, that it opens in a separate window rather than inside my app? Currently, iAd banner is all set up working in ViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the apple documentation, they have the property:

```
bannerViewActionInProgress
A Boolean value that states whether the banner is currently executing an user-triggered action. (read-only)

@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isBannerViewActionInProgress) BOOL bannerViewActionInProgress
Discussion
Advertisements have an action that is triggered when the user taps the banner. Some actions remain in the application, covering the application’s user interface until the action completes. The value of this property is YES when such an action is running; otherwise it is NO.

Your application should avoid polling this property. Instead, implement the delegate methods to detect when an action begins or ends.

Availability
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
Declared In
ADBannerView.h
```

Which might be what you need.